# Find best AWS EC2 zone for given IP address

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ping

Is there an easy way to determine AWS EC2 region with lowest ping to given public IP address?

There is a server hosted by third party. I only know the IP address of the server. Given that I'm looking to find the EC2 region with best ping to that server. I can't ping AWS servers from the third party server.

Edit: I meant region, not availability zone.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Do you mean availability zone or region? They're not the same

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your meaning region rather than Availability zone:

http://www.cloudping.info/

If you want more detail than that run an MTR to IPs in that region (doesn't need to complete) to get an idea of what the path from you to that region is like.